# How come I cannot use arrays from a class structure when passing data into a dictionary to create a pandas dataframe table?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Here is the code that produces a faulty data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt



class mouse:
list_players = (["Spacelyon", "Cloak", "Jaomock", "Tfue", "Tennp0", "Avxry", "Cizzorz", "Thiefs", "Yelo", "Replays"])

list_dpi = ([800.0, 400.0, 800.0, 400.0, 800.0, 800.0, 600.0, 650.0, 400.0, 1200.0])
ray_dpi = np.array(list_dpi)

list_sens = ([.75, 1.00, .8, .7, .85, .75, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, .74])
ray_sens = np.array(list_sens)

list_xsens = ([.15, .12, .15, .08, .11, .08, .08, .10, .15, .10])
ray_xsens = np.array(list_xsens)

list_ysens = ([.15, .12, .10, .08, .11, .05, .08, .07, .10, .07])
ray_ysens = np.array(list_ysens)


def global_sort(self, sorted_dpi, sorted_sens, sorted_xsens, sorted_ysens):
    self.ray_dpi = sorted_dpi,
    self.ray_sens = sorted_sens,
    self.ray_xsens = sorted_xsens,
    self.ray_ysens = sorted_ysens
sorted_dpi = np.sort(ray_dpi)
sorted_sens = np.sort(ray_sens)
sorted_xsens = np.sort(ray_xsens)
sorted_ysens = np.sort(ray_ysens)






#instanceiated
m = mouse()

####Single definition call
#m.global_sort(m.sorted_dpi, m.sorted_sens, m.sorted_xsens, m.sorted_ysens)


player_data = {
'players': [m.list_players],
'dpi' : [m.ray_dpi], 
'sens' : [m.ray_sens], 
'xsens': [m.ray_xsens], 
'ysens': [m.ray_ysens]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(player_data, columns = ["players", "dpi", "sens", "xsens", 
"ysens"] )
df.to_csv('fortnite_mouse_settings.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('fortnite_mouse_settings.csv')

print(df)
```

vs code where manually import the data into the dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt



class mouse:
list_players = (["Spacelyon", "Cloak", "Jaomock", "Tfue", "Tennp0", "Avxry", "Cizzorz", "Thiefs", "Yelo", "Replays"])

list_dpi = ([800.0, 400.0, 800.0, 400.0, 800.0, 800.0, 600.0, 650.0, 400.0, 1200.0])
ray_dpi = np.array(list_dpi)

list_sens = ([.75, 1.00, .8, .7, .85, .75, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, .74])
ray_sens = np.array(list_sens)

list_xsens = ([.15, .12, .15, .08, .11, .08, .08, .10, .15, .10])
ray_xsens = np.array(list_xsens)

list_ysens = ([.15, .12, .10, .08, .11, .05, .08, .07, .10, .07])
ray_ysens = np.array(list_ysens)


def global_sort(self, sorted_dpi, sorted_sens, sorted_xsens, sorted_ysens):
    self.ray_dpi = sorted_dpi,
    self.ray_sens = sorted_sens,
    self.ray_xsens = sorted_xsens,
    self.ray_ysens = sorted_ysens
sorted_dpi = np.sort(ray_dpi)
sorted_sens = np.sort(ray_sens)
sorted_xsens = np.sort(ray_xsens)
sorted_ysens = np.sort(ray_ysens)






#instanceiated
m = mouse()

####Single definition call
#m.global_sort(m.sorted_dpi, m.sorted_sens, m.sorted_xsens, m.sorted_ysens)


player_data = {
'players': ["Spacelyon", "Cloak", "Jaomock", "Tfue", "Tennp0", "Avxry", "Cizzorz", "Thiefs", "Yelo", "Replays"],
'dpi' : [800.0, 400.0, 800.0, 400.0, 800.0, 800.0, 600.0, 650.0, 400.0, 1200.0], 
'sens' : [.75, 1.00, .8, .7, .85, .75, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, .74], 
'xsens': [.15, .12, .15, .08, .11, .08, .08, .10, .15, .10], 
'ysens': [.15, .12, .10, .08, .11, .05, .08, .07, .10, .07]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(player_data, columns = ["players", "dpi", "sens", "xsens", "ysens"] )
df.to_csv('fortnite_mouse_settings.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('fortnite_mouse_settings.csv')

print(df)
```

My question is why cant I use arrays from the class I created when creating a dictionary for pandas data frame? I am only 3 days into learning python and I feel like this problem is counter intuitive. Not sure what I am supposed to do here..

Comment: Also ignore the sorting definition right now. that is for later. Was just learning and decided to leave it because why not for now.

Comment: Please don't include irrelevant code in the question. Also, please indent the code correctly since whitespaces does matter in python.